# FabricJS: big grid objects is blurry

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, fabricjs

I want to draw a large grid with fabricjs, but it is too blurry. I use fabricJS `canvas.toSVG()` export to a svg file, and I open the svg file in browser, it's view good. so I think this is most possible likely a bug for edge.

**The test code is:**

```js
var data = [];
    var temp = [0,0,-0.012,-0.012,-0.012,-0.012,-0.012,-0.012,0,0,-0.012,-0.012,0,0.049,0.073,0.049,0.049,0.037,-0.012,-0.012,-0.024,-0.049,-0.024,-0.049,-0.061,-0.012,-0.061,-0.086,0.061,0.146,0.354,0.403,-0.647,-1.88,-1.672,-0.757,-0.33,-0.098,0.024,0.012,0.073,0.122,0.098,0.146,0.183,0.171,0.207,0.232];
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        data = data.concat(temp);
    }
    
    // case 1 : blurry
    var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas("ecg1");
    var width   = 8000;
    var height  = 400;
    canvas1.setWidth(width);
    canvas1.setHeight(height);
    var bg1  = getBackgroundPath(width, height);
    var ecg1 = getEcgPath(data);
    canvas1.add(bg1);
    canvas1.add(ecg1);
    canvas1.renderAll(); // blurry
    
    // case 2 : ok
    var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas("ecg2");
    var data2 = data.slice(0, 3000);
    width   = 1000;
    height  = 400;
    canvas2.setWidth(width);
    canvas2.setHeight(height);
    var bg2  = getBackgroundPath(width, height);
    var ecg2 = getEcgPath(data2);
    canvas2.add(bg2);
    canvas2.add(ecg2);
    canvas2.renderAll();
    
    // case 3 : blurry
    var canvas3 = new fabric.Canvas("ecg3");
    canvas3.setWidth(width);
    canvas3.setHeight(height);
    canvas3.add(new fabric.Group([bg2, ecg2]));
    canvas3.renderAll();
    
    function getBackgroundPath(width, height) {
        var grid = [];
        for (var y = 0; y <= height; y += 10) {
            grid.push("M");
            grid.push("0");
            grid.push(y);
            grid.push("H");
            grid.push(width);
        }
        for (var x = 0; x <= width; x += 10) {
            grid.push("M");
            grid.push(x);
            grid.push("0");
            grid.push("V");
            grid.push(height);
        }
        return new fabric.Path(grid.join(" "), {
            top  : 0,
            left : 0,
            stroke: 'pink',
            strokeWidth: 1
        });
    }
    function getEcgPath(data) {
        var xm = 2;
        var ym = 100;
        var max  = Math.max.apply(Math, data);
        var path = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            path.push("L");
            path.push(i * xm);
            path.push((max - data[i]) * ym);
        }
        path[0] = "M";
        return new fabric.Path(path.join(" "), {
            top  : 0,
            left : 0,
            fill : '',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 1
        });
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="ecg1"></canvas>
  <canvas id="ecg2"></canvas>
  <canvas id="ecg3"></canvas>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.3/fabric.min.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the result is
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have further reading here:
http://fabricjs.com/fabric-object-caching

This question is actually easily solvable disabling caching for the ECG line.
If your application needs to draw just a big path or an handfull of them, caching is not necessary.

How caching works?
Caching draw the object on a separate canvas and then reuse that canvas every frame when you move it.
This is way more performing than having to execute multiple fill and stroke operation each frame for many objects, especially when objects are complex.

To avoid performances pitfall the canvas used for caching is limited to 2 mega pixels by default ( you can push it up changing fabric.perfLimitSizeTotal ) and whatever is the mega pixel size, the largest size is limited to 4096 by default ( if you do not need to support ie11 you can make it bigger changing fabric.maxCacheSideLimit ).

In your case the path is smoothly handled by the cpu.

For the grid we need some more code.

```js
var data = [];
    var temp = [0,0,-0.012,-0.012,-0.012,-0.012,-0.012,-0.012,0,0,-0.012,-0.012,0,0.049,0.073,0.049,0.049,0.037,-0.012,-0.012,-0.024,-0.049,-0.024,-0.049,-0.061,-0.012,-0.061,-0.086,0.061,0.146,0.354,0.403,-0.647,-1.88,-1.672,-0.757,-0.33,-0.098,0.024,0.012,0.073,0.122,0.098,0.146,0.183,0.171,0.207,0.232];
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        data = data.concat(temp);
    }
    
    // case 1 : blurry
    var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas("ecg1");
    var width   = 8000;
    var height  = 400;
    canvas1.setWidth(width);
    canvas1.setHeight(height);
    var bg1  = getBackgroundPath(width, height);
    var ecg1 = getEcgPath(data);
    canvas1.add(bg1);
    canvas1.add(ecg1);
    canvas1.renderAll(); // blurry
    
    
    function getBackgroundPath(width, height) {
        var grid = [];
        for (var y = 0; y <= height; y += 10) {
            grid.push("M");
            grid.push("0");
            grid.push(y);
            grid.push("H");
            grid.push(width);
        }
        for (var x = 0; x <= width; x += 10) {
            grid.push("M");
            grid.push(x);
            grid.push("0");
            grid.push("V");
            grid.push(height);
        }
        return new fabric.Path(grid.join(" "), {
            top  : 0,
            left : 0,
            stroke: 'pink',
            strokeWidth: 1
        });
    }
    function getEcgPath(data) {
        var xm = 2;
        var ym = 100;
        var max  = Math.max.apply(Math, data);
        var path = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            path.push("L");
            path.push(i * xm);
            path.push((max - data[i]) * ym);
        }
        path[0] = "M";
        return new fabric.Path(path.join(" "), {
            top  : 0,
            left : 0,
            fill : '',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            objectCaching: false,
        });
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="ecg1"></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.3/fabric.min.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I disable cache, it's view ok.`fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false`

Answer (score 0):

@AndreaBogazzi

Thanks your answer. After I use `fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false`, it's shows good.

In my application, the draw grid code is as follows.

```js
var data = [];
    var temp = [0,0,-0.012,-0.012,-0.012,-0.012,-0.012,-0.012,0,0,-0.012,-0.012,0,0.049,0.073,0.049,0.049,0.037,-0.012,-0.012,-0.024,-0.049,-0.024,-0.049,-0.061,-0.012,-0.061,-0.086,0.061,0.146,0.354,0.403,-0.647,-1.88,-1.672,-0.757,-0.33,-0.098,0.024,0.012,0.073,0.122,0.098,0.146,0.183,0.171,0.207,0.232];
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        data = data.concat(temp);
    }
    
    // case 1 : blurry
    var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas("ecg1");
    var width   = 8000;
    var height  = 400;
    canvas1.setWidth(width);
    canvas1.setHeight(height);
    var bg11 = getBackgroundDot(width, height);
    var bg12 = getBackgroundPath(width, height);
    var ecg1 = getEcgPath(data);
    canvas1.add(bg11);
    canvas1.add(bg12);
    canvas1.add(ecg1);
    canvas1.renderAll(); // blurry
    
    function getBackgroundDot() {
        var dotLineWidth = 2;
        var dot = [];
        dot.push("M 0 0");
        for (var y = 0; y <= height; y += 10) {
            if (y % 50 == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            dot.push("M");
            dot.push("0");
            dot.push(y);
            dot.push("H");
            dot.push(width);
        }
        var sda = [0, 10];
        for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            sda.push(dotLineWidth);
            sda.push(8);
        }
        return new fabric.Path(dot.join(" "), {
            top  : 0,
            left : 0,
            stroke: 'pink',
            strokeWidth: dotLineWidth,
            strokeDashArray: sda
        });
    }
    
    function getBackgroundPath(width, height) {
        var grid = [];
        for (var y = 0; y <= height; y += 50) {
            grid.push("M");
            grid.push("0");
            grid.push(y);
            grid.push("H");
            grid.push(width);
        }
        for (var x = 0; x <= width; x += 50) {
            grid.push("M");
            grid.push(x);
            grid.push("0");
            grid.push("V");
            grid.push(height);
        }
        return new fabric.Path(grid.join(" "), {
            top  : 0,
            left : 0,
            stroke: 'pink',
            strokeWidth: 1
        });
    }
    
    function getEcgPath(data) {
        var xm = 2;
        var ym = 100;
        var max  = Math.max.apply(Math, data);
        var path = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            path.push("L");
            path.push(i * xm);
            path.push((max - data[i]) * ym);
        }
        path[0] = "M";
        return new fabric.Path(path.join(" "), {
            top  : 0,
            left : 0,
            fill : '',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 1
        });
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    
<canvas id="ecg1"></canvas>
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.3/fabric.min.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false` it will disable whole object cache, which is not a good solution.

Comment: yes, but it's enouph in my application. You can add a cache to the specified object.
`new fabric.Path(grid.join(" "), {objectCaching: false});`